# cannot unhide element in autodesk

Tags: autodesk

I have multiple walls, floors, and other elements hidden in my Autodesk model.

**#1 I tried :** the "light-bulb"/reveal button; then selecting the wall; then right clicking and selecting the option "hide in view". Element & Category are "grayed out" and cannot be selected. The "By filter" option is not grayed out.

**#2 I tried:** going to the the View Tab and the Visibility and Graphics button. All of the boxes were checked as visible in that view.

Can someone please give me other ideas or solutions to try and fix this problem?
As always I greatly appreciate your help.
Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 0):

Well I couldn't find a way to fix it so I just shutdown Autodesk then reopened my project. That did the trick! All hidden elements are now unhidden.

If someone has a better fix for this anomaly that I ran into with the options being grayed out and elements not unhidding then please feel free to post.